# onunload event of JavaScript does not work in Linux Firefox

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Can you help me with this problem? I am using Mozilla Firefox in Linux.
When I close the window or reload the page the `onunload` event does not work:

```
<html>
  <head>

    <title>onunload test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     window.onunload = unloadPage;

      function unloadPage()
      {
        alert("unload event detected!");
      }
  </script>
 </head>

 <body>
     <p>Reload a new page into the browser<br />
     to fire the unload event for this page.</p>
     <p>You can also use the back or forward buttons<br />
     to load a new page and fire this event.</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code snippet :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
      return 'Are you sure you want to leave?'; // or anything you want to do
      };
```

Comment: Thanks It work perfect But ask me confirmation . It can be done without confirmation?

Comment: `window.onunload = function() {
    alert('Bye.');
}` will work on IE but unfortunately firefox and chrome blocks the `alert()` on `onunload`use `console.log` instead

Answer (score -1):

try to use jQuery  libraries, because jquery consider different kinds of browser i think :)

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
    alert( "unload event detected!" );
});
```